# SSRS Aggregate Summation by ReportItems

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, reporting-services, sum

I have the following structure

[image]

Details contain summation of fields, an inner grouping on zone_desc, and an outer grouping on price type. I am looking to sum the seats field by zone. Currently the detailed row for seats is a summation of other columns and looks like this `=ReportItems!sold_seats.Value + ReportItems!consignment.Value + ReportItems!comps.Value`

I am trying to perform an aggregation on a calculated Field seats by zone in SSRS and am getting the following error:

`[rsAggregateReportItemInBody] The Value expression for the textrun 'total_seats2.Paragraphs[0].TextRuns[0]' uses an aggregate function on a report item.  Aggregate functions can be used only on report items contained in page headers and footers.`

I've tried a variety of ways to sum it.

`=sum(ReportItems!sold_seats.Value + ReportItems!consignment.Value + ReportItems!comps.Value)`
or

`=sum(ReportItems!total_seats.Value)`
or

`=sum(ReportItems!total_seats.Value, "zone_desc")`
or

`=sum(fields!total_seats.Value)`
or

`=sum(fields!total_seats.Value, "zone_desc")`
or

as advised in a post elsewhere

*Note: I can't make the changes in the source file, I'm stuck with the confines of the sql proc as it is. I'm also stuck with the confines of multiple groupings. We are basically migrating a report from an old system (Sybase/infomaker) to SSRS and need to mimic set up exactly and just improve functionality as per the users stern request. Additionally I'm displaying one column we have to sum up, but in truth there are 8 in total so we need to come up with a solution that will work across the board.*